# access file-system file with my browser

Tags: java, javascript, file-upload, filesystems, browser

Can i access my local file system files with my browser? I think it is possible, I found one mozilla firefox plugin which does the same.

As per my understanding, the way upload functionality of a browser works, in the same way we can do traversing of files.

Please provide provide me some link to know about the "upload functionality" of a browser, how does it contact to the filesystem to upload any file from a given path.

Or can I write ay client side script which can do traversing?

Comment: For browsers supporting the File API, you can select folders to drop into file `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to let the client upload a file, there's no need for plugins or Java or anything such. Just use [`FileUpload`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) in a `form`.

Comment: no, i don't want to upload any file. I want to contact file system to traverse all the files in that (Path will be given by the user).

Comment: Then no, you can't do that with the basic browser, because that's a major security risk. You could do this with a signed Java applet.

Comment: but to access it, we need "latest version" of java to be installed in the system which is a drawback. Currently, I am using Java Swing but it is working in only few systems. and in which machine it is not working, we don't have permission to install anything. Any way, to handle this situation?

Comment: No. Not being able to access the user's files is a security feature (you don't want random Web pages grabbing files off your hard drive), and only some explicit permission, like `FileUpload` or user approval of a signed applet (or Web Start program) will allow you to.

Comment: thats what i need, how is this "explicit permission" works? where is it defined, how is it avaliable for FileUpload only. Where can i find this details?

Comment: `FileUpload` is an HTML form element that tells the browser to have the user select a file to upload. (You'll see this frequently for picture uploads; even the rich editor here has it.) It pops up a regular OS "select file" dialog. If you want to go traversing the filesystem yourself, you'll have to run a program (e.g., applet, Web Start) on the user's computer, and this will require an installed JRE. No way around it.

Comment: @chrylis...what will you say about JCIFS library..using it..can i fulfill my requirement?